# Load different webView when a button is pressed

Tags: android

I would load different webView in order changing by a next and a previous button like:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://developer.android.com/");
```

and when the next button is pressed

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
```

and if the previous button is pressed return to the first.

There is a way to do that?

This is the code that work for me

```
String[] urls = {"http://developer.android.com/", "http://google.com/"};
 int currentPage = 0;

 public void next(View view){ 
 try {
     if (currentPage != urls.length - 1){
         currentPage++;
         wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         wv.loadUrl(urls[currentPage]);

     }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. You should implement some method in activity and execute it in `android:onClick` in XML:

In `Activity`:

```
 String ulrs = String[]{"http://developer.android.com/", "http://google.com", (some other)};
 int currentPage = 0;

 public void next(View view){
     if (currentPage != urls.length - 1){
         currentPage++;
         webview.loadUrl(urls[currentPage]);
     }
 }
```

In layout XML:

```
 <Button
  android:id="+@id/next_button"
  (some layout code)
  android:onClick="next" />
```

Prev button code is analogical.

[button tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

Comment: I know, but i want change the webView displayed when the button is pressed, and not whit only another webView

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. You want to change the url displayed or change to another `WebView` object? If url displayed, then doesn't `loadUrl` do this?

Comment: Yes, but i have to display like 6 different url, and change the url by the button

Comment: Why not storing URL as the `String` and updating it after button click and then loading everything with `loadUrl`?

Comment: Yes but i dont know how